# создания поля в sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

создается таблица в которой одно из полей - это уникальный номер и должен быть представлен в виде dd_dd (где _ - пробел), мои варианты ниже не работают корректно, то есть таблица создается, но в нее невозможно ввести данные..код:

```
CREATE TABLE man
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    number INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (number LIKE '[0-9][0-9]\s[0-9][0-9]')
);
```

варианты CHECK ниже таже не заработали:

```
CHECK (number LIKE '[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]')
CHECK (number LIKE '[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}')
CHECK (number LIKE '[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}')
CHECK (number LIKE '-- --')
```

Comment: INTEGER - целое число. В числах не может быть пробелов. Вероятно, вам нужно изменить тип этого поля.

Answer (score 1):

С одной стороны, в данном случае достаточно изменить тип поля `number` с `int` на `char(5)`:

```
CREATE TABLE man
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    number CHAR(5) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CK_man_number
            CHECK (number LIKE '[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]'),
    CONSTRAINT PK_man PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

С другой, форматирование чаще отводится фронт-энду, и, возможно, стоит подумать о том, чтобы хранить уникальный номер в числовом формате, напр. `smallint` (2 байта против 5 у `char(5)`):

```
CREATE TABLE man
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    number smallint NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CK_man_number
            CHECK (number between 1000 and 9999),
    CONSTRAINT PK_man PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Также, в Sql Server начиная с версии 2012 появилась функция `FORMAT`. В случае с полем типа `smallint` выражение `FORMAT(number, '## ##')` (если это действительно требуется в запросах) даст нужное форматирование. Можно его даже оформить в виде *calculated column*.

Comment: что такое NULL CONSTRAINT CK_man_number и CONSTRAINT PK_man ??

Comment: @user192633, `CK_man_number` и `PK_man` есть _явное указание имени_ для `CHECK` и `PRIMARY KEY` ограничений. Это рекомендуется делать (для _НЕ_ временных таблиц). Если имена не указывать явно, то они будут заданы системой, что-то типа `CK__man__number__047E9CB5` и `PK__man__3213E83F02965443`. Чтобы проверить, после создания таблицы, выполните `select object_name(constid) from sys.sysconstraints where id = object_id('man')`.

Comment: @user192633, в принципе это, наверное, не страшно, когда БД одна и изменения в схеме делаются вручную. Если же их несколько одинаковых (напр. тестовая, демо и рабочая, или несколько рабочих), то при системном именовании в каждом инстансе имена будут разные. В дальнейшем, если потребуется изменить условие `CHECK` или изменить `PRIMARY KEY` (напр. сделать его не кластерным), не пересоздавая таблицу, то написать `ALTER` скрипт, который бы одинаково сработал в любом инстансе БД, будет _существенно_ проще.